# Access accounts in two ExactTarget environments using single .jar

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

I have two different accounts in Exact Target in production environment. One account is for Live and other is to be used for development/testing. I am using Java API. However, I want to use a single .jar file but depending on a particular parameter being passed from the back-end, I would like to channelize data to appropriate DE or Publication list. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Axis2 in order to access the services and have started using the example project that is available, please check out: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_api_using_java_and_axis2/

There is a section that was added recently called "Handling Accounts in Multiple Environments Using a Single Codebase" which should be what you are looking for.